# JAXB Release Documentation stating contrary information about Compile and Runtime Jars

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-ws, maven-3

Referred to the following JAXB release documentation.

https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.11/docs/release-documentation.html#section-2232462900667844

It states that it needs following jars at Runtime

```
jaxb-api.jar, jaxb-core.jar, jaxb-impl.jar,
```

But in the next line, same documentation also states that it does not needs same jars at Runtime. This seems incorrect information. What is correct information? Where can it be found?

Furthermore, the documentation on the following link

https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.3u1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html

states that only

```
jaxb-xjc.jar
```

is needed at compile time.

I do understand that the two documentations are for different versions, but still the first link seems contradictory to itself.

I am actually trying to implement a Jaxws based web service and want to ensure that I am not including extra Jars for no reason. Therefore, I need to understand what JAXWS jars are needed at compile time and what are needed at Runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the link clearly states,

`jaxb-api.jar, jaxb-core.jar, jaxb-impl.jar` are required at runtime.

`jaxb-api.jar, jaxb-core.jar, jaxb-impl.jar, jaxb-xjc.jar` are required at compile time.

Your other link is for an older version of JAXB 2.2 so you should ignore it.

Comment: The first link actually says "Jars required at your development environment (but not runtime)" This is contradictory.

Comment: @DolphinJava the wording could be better, I agree, but it's obvious to me what they meant